# inserting data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to check by ID and email but the code below does not work, thank you for helping me
the following steps performed

verification by facebook id

- if there id ==> Update BD and redirect home.php
- if id does not exist we will checks if the email (retrieved from facebook) exists on the BD
- if yes ==> display "this email is already used"
- if not ==> insert on database and ==> redirect to home.php

  ```
  $cont = $idf;

  $idf = $user_profile['id'];

  $email = $user_profile['email'];

  $query = "SELECT idf from users where idf = $idf ";
  $result = mysql_query($query);


  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1)


  {
      // row exists. so update

      mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name = '".$name."', birthday = '".$birthday."', gender = '".$gender."', email = '".$email."' WHERE idf = '".$idf."';") or die(mysqli_error());

  header( "refresh:4;url=/home.php" );

  } 

  else 

  {

  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $email ";
     $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error());

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)



   echo "This Email is already used.";

  }

    else


  {

      // row  does not exists. so create new
      //insertion dans la base de donnée
  $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, birthday, gender,idl,idf ) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$birthday."', '".$gender."',NULL,'".$idf."');");

  //mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());


  //echo 'Le cookie existe   ' . $cont . '<br />';

  mysql_close();

  setcookie("cokiz", $cont, time()+3600, "/", "NDD");
  setcookie("cokiz", $cont, time()+3600, "/", "NDD");

  header( "refresh:4;url=/home.php" );


  }
  }


  ?>
  ```

Comment: `mysql_query` or `mysqli_query` One or another, no both. mysql_* it's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

```
    use this this will work i think so , use myl_sqli_query  or  mysql_query

    $cont = $idf;

    $idf = $user_profile['id'];

    $email = $user_profile['email'];

    $query = "SELECT idf from users where idf = $idf ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);


    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1)


    {
        // row exists. so update

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name = '".$name."', birthday = '".$birthday."', gender = '".$gender."', email = '".$email."' WHERE idf = '".$idf."';") or die(mysqli_error());

    header( "refresh:4;url=/home.php" );

    } 

    else 

    {

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $email ";
       $result1 = mysql_query($mysql,$sql1) or die(mysql_error());

       if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0)



     echo "This Email is already used.";

    }

      else


    {

        // row  does not exists. so create new
        //insertion dans la base de donnée
    $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, birthday, gender,idl,idf ) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$birthday."', '".$gender."',NULL,'".$idf."');");

    //mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());


    //echo 'Le cookie existe   ' . $cont . '<br />';

    mysql_close();

    setcookie("cokiz", $cont, time()+3600, "/", "NDD");
    setcookie("cokiz", $cont, time()+3600, "/", "NDD");

    header( "refresh:4;url=/home.php" );


    }
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: using this code there is no display (loading icon) no redirection

Answer (score 0):

the error is that you missed

```
{
```

before the line :

```
echo "This Email is already used.";
```

Comment: after adding the character "{" page appears (loading icon) but the redirection does not work

Answer (score 0):

This code is ok: (verification only by ID):

```
$idf = $user_profile['id'];

$cont = $idf;

$query = "SELECT idf from users where idf = $idf ";
$result = mysql_query($query);


if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1)
{
    // row exists. so update

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name = '".$name."', birthday = '".$birthday."', gender = '".$gender."', email = '".$email."' WHERE idf = '".$idf."';");
} else {
//echo $email;
    // row  does not exists. so create new
    //insertion dans la base de donnée
$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, birthday, gender,idl,idf ) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$birthday."', '".$gender."',NULL,'".$idf."');");

//mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());


//echo 'Le cookie existe   ' . $cont . '<br />';

mysql_close();

setcookie("cokiz", $cont, time()+3600, "/", "NDD");
setcookie("cokiz", $cont, time()+3600, "/", "NDD");

header( "refresh:4;url=/home.php" );


}

?>
```

but when I add verification by mail: it does not work  (code below)

```
$cont = $idf;

    $idf = $user_profile['id'];

    $email = $user_profile['email'];

    $query = "SELECT idf from users where idf = $idf ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);


    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1)




    {
        // row exists. so update

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name = '".$name."', birthday = '".$birthday."', gender = '".$gender."', email = '".$email."' WHERE idf = '".$idf."';");


    } 

    else 

    {

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $email ";
       $result1 = mysql_query($mysql,$sql1) or die(mysql_error());


       if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0)

 {

     echo "This Email is already used.";

    }

      else


    {

        // row  does not exists. so create new
        //insertion dans la base de donnée
    $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, birthday, gender,idl,idf ) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$birthday."', '".$gender."',NULL,'".$idf."');");

    mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());


    //echo 'Le cookie existe   ' . $cont . '<br />';

    mysql_close();

    setcookie("cokiz", $cont, time()+3600, "/", "NDD");
    setcookie("cokiz", $cont, time()+3600, "/", "NDD");

    header( "refresh:4;url=/home.php" );

    }
    }



    ?>
```

someone has an idea? thanks